# No top user for most sites in users league

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

In the [Stack Exchange - Top Users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) tab, for most of the sites there is no top user displayed.

I didn't see any error or warning in the browser's console and network tabs.

GIF for the same:

> [image: GIF]

**Configuration:**

OS: Windows 7
Mozilla Firefox : 59.0b5 (64-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu using Firefox 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed.

> This code was recently ported over to the Q&A code base, so we can call methods instead of making HTTP API calls on the back-end (leagues are also used for the "top N% .." rank string on the user profile). While moving cheese we missed a bit in the /leagues view; it was still using an invalid SE site id when trying to show data for an (Q&A) site (Sites have different ids in SE, but we're working on remedying that as well).

Comment: Why did you use spoiler formatting here?